# Convert Excel sheet data to HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I'm using this js application found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u7R7yuQ6g9Y

```js
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

      if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
            document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

            excel_file.value = '';

            return false;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

      reader.onload = function (event) {

            var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

            var work_book = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });

            var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

            var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], { header: 1 });

            if (sheet_data.length > 0) {
                  var table_output = '<table class="listViewTable table-sortable" id="listViewTable">';

                  for (var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++) {

                        table_output += '<tr class="ce1 colorYellow">';

                        for (var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++) {

                              if (row == 0) {

                                    table_output += '<th class="name1 hsText">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</th>';

                              }
                              else {

                                    table_output += '<td class="entry1 hsText">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</td>';

                              }

                        }

                        table_output += '</tr>';

                  }

                  table_output += '</table>';

                  document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
            }

            excel_file.value = '';

      }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="excel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's what I need: Some columns need different styling. How can I get an output like this:

```
<tr class="row-one">
<td class="column-one-data-cell"></td>
<td class="column-two-data-cell"></td>
<td class="column-three-data-cell"></td>
</tr>
```

and in a different case something like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-4">
    <p class="amount">content of column 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
    <p class="unit">content of column 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

That would make it possible to do so much more with it, like also write the data in a bootstrap grid system with different styles for different cols etc.

Here are two examples for the desired output:

#1: For HTML Table with different classes for different columns:

| table-th-c1 | table-th-c2 | table-th-c3 | table-th-c4 | table-th-c5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Column 1, class 1 | Column 2, class 2 | Column 3, class 3 | Column 4, class 4 | Column 5, class 5 |
| Column 1, class 1 | Column 2, class 2 | Column 3, class 3 | Column 4, class 4 | Column 5, class 5 |
| Column 1, class 1 | Column 2, class 2 | Column 3, class 3 | Column 4, class 4 | Column 5, class 5 |
| Column 1, class 1 | Column 2, class 2 | Column 3, class 3 | Column 4, class 4 | Column 5, class 5 |

#2: For the bootstrap grid system:

| table-th-c1 | table-th-c2 | table-th-c3 | table-th-c4 | table-th-c5 | Table-th-c6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Container 1, Row 1, Column 1 | Container 1, Row 2, Column 1 | Container 1, Row 2, Column 2 | Container 1, Row 3, Column 1 | Container 1, Row 3, Column 2 | Container 1, Row 3, Column 3 |
| Container 2, Row 1, Column 1 | Container 2, Row 2, Column 1 | Container 2, Row 2, Column 2 | Container 2, Row 3, Column 1 | Container 2, Row 3, Column 2 | Container 2, Row 3, Column 3 |
| Container 3, Row 1, Column 1 | Container 3, Row 2, Column 1 | Container 3, Row 2, Column 2 | Container 3, Row 3, Column 1 | Container 3, Row 3, Column 2 | Container 3, Row 3, Column 3 |
| Container 4, Row 1, Column 1 | Container 4, Row 2, Column 1 | Container 4, Row 2, Column 2 | Container 4, Row 3, Column 1 | Container 4, Row 3, Column 2 | Container 4, Row 3, Column 3 |

Thank you for your help; it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow! I'm very impressed by the demo. I didn't know that we could get a free JS lib to handle sheets and even read Excel sheets! Thanks for sharing. I had a look on the [documentation of HTML output](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs#html-output) and I don't see much options. But perhaps they would be a way to override the library, I don't know. If not, you could export to JSON and then generate your HTML yourself in JS if your data is simple. It depends on what you load, of course.

Comment: Pleasure to share this with you :) So let's have a look: Table_output is a string, += adds everything behind it. What's inside the  '  apostrophes are string literals, i.e. exactly the text that is also in the code, right? But you can also stick other variables to your table_output, and in cell you always have the column in which you are and you go from cell to cell. Do you think that could work? Anyone here who's able to create a working example?

Comment: Look Add CSS to HTML from Excel
https://github.com/VM1968/myXLSX.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to just answer it in the way you have chosen; **(Defining many classes - Not good way)**

(Just you have to know how to deal with `strings` in `loop`)

The example code should be something like this:

```
table_output += '<th class="row' + row + '-cell' + cell + '">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</th>';
```

```js
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

      if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
            document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

            excel_file.value = '';

            return false;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

      reader.onload = function (event) {

            var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

            var work_book = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });

            var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

            var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], { header: 1 });

            if (sheet_data.length > 0) {
                  var table_output = '<table class="listViewTable table-sortable" id="listViewTable">';

                  for (var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++) {

                        table_output += '<tr class="row'+row+'">';

                        for (var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++) {

                              if (row == 0) {

                                    table_output += '<th class="row' + row + '-cell' + cell + '">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</th>';

                              } else {

                                    table_output += '<td class="row'+row+'-cell'+cell+'">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</td>';

                              }

                        }

                        table_output += '</tr>';

                  }

                  table_output += '</table>';

                  document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
            }

            excel_file.value = '';

      }

});
```

```css
.row2-cell2{color:red}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="excel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

##### But what you actually need is [Tree-structural pseudo-classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#tree-structural_pseudo-classes):

The [`:nth-child`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) can handle it, even better than what you expect:

###### How customize a specific cell in a HTML table, without define a class or id?

```css
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) {
  color: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(1) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 1 - Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 1 - Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 1 - Col 3</td>
    <td>Row 1 - Col 4</td>
    <td>Row 1 - Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 2 - Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Col 3</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Col 4</td>
    <td>Row 2 - Col 5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row 3 - Col 1</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Col 2</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Col 3</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Col 4</td>
    <td>Row 3 - Col 5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Of course! Now that's really easy, I feel really stupid now, but more than that, I'm very happy :D Thank you so much! Me and a friend of mine are having a look at how to do that with the bootstrap grid now.

Comment: @stst your welcome. don't feel like that, It is how programmers learn. Also the library have some example, check the website: https://sheetjs.com/

Comment: Hey, i hope it's okay to come back to that again. If you could show me one last thing I would understand it completely, I still can't figure out how to do it. What would be the output command for example #1 above? So that just every column gets a different class, same for every row (in your example, every new row gets new classes, which is of course not good at all). That way I would be able to simply use find and replace to change that to bootstrap grid.

Comment: @stst as i said, first you have to research about how to deal with strings in loops. Then you have to know better about [tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table). I think bootstrap grid work with `display:block` elements, like `div`. So string structure should completely change. First change all `table` or `th` or `td` to `div`. Then set classes static, Example: `table_output += '<div class="col">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</div>';`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, [MMMahdy-PAPION](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7514010/mmmahdy-papion)!

I just found out how to change the code to get the result that I was looking for:

```js
const excel_file = document.getElementById('excel_file');

excel_file.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

      if (!['application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/vnd.ms-excel'].includes(event.target.files[0].type)) {
            document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Only .xlsx or .xls file format are allowed</div>';

            excel_file.value = '';

            return false;
      }

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.target.files[0]);

      reader.onload = function (event) {

            var data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

            var work_book = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });

            var sheet_name = work_book.SheetNames;

            var sheet_data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(work_book.Sheets[sheet_name[0]], { header: 1 });

            if (sheet_data.length > 0) {
                  var table_output = '<table class="listViewTable table-sortable" id="listViewTable">';

                  for (var row = 0; row < sheet_data.length; row++) {

                        table_output += '<tr class="row">';

                        for (var cell = 0; cell < sheet_data[row].length; cell++) {

                              if (row == 0) {

                                    table_output += '<th class="row' + '-cell' + cell + '">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</th>';

                              } else {

                                    table_output += '<td class="row' + '-cell' + cell + '">' + sheet_data[row][cell] + '</td>';

                              }

                        }

                        table_output += '</tr>';

                  }

                  table_output += '</table>';

                  document.getElementById('excel_data').innerHTML = table_output;
            }

            excel_file.value = '';

      }

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/xlsx@0.15.1/dist/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4 mb-4">Convert Excel to HTML Table using JavaScript</h2>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header"><b>Select Excel File</b></div>
            <div class="card-body">
                
                <input type="file" id="excel_file" />

            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="excel_data" class="mt-5"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="excel.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now the output looks like this:

```
<table class="listViewTable table-sortable" id="listViewTable">
        <tbody>
              <tr class="row">
                    <th class="row-cell0">NAME</th>
                    <th class="row-cell1">DATA-1</th>
                    <th class="row-cell2">DATA-2</th>
                    <th class="row-cell3">DATA-3</th>
                    <th class="row-cell4">DATA-4</th>
                    <th class="row-cell5">DATA-5</th>
              </tr>
              <tr class="row">
                    <td class="row-cell0">ITEM1</td>
                    <td class="row-cell1">DATA-COL-1</td>
                    <td class="row-cell2">DATA-COL-2</td>
                    <td class="row-cell3">DATA-COL-3</td>
                    <td class="row-cell4">DATA-COL-4</td>
                    <td class="row-cell5">DATA-COL-5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="row">
                    <td class="row-cell0">ITEM2</td>
                    <td class="row-cell1">DATA-COL-1</td>
                    <td class="row-cell2">DATA-COL-2</td>
                    <td class="row-cell3">DATA-COL-3</td>
                    <td class="row-cell4">DATA-COL-4</td>
                    <td class="row-cell5">DATA-COL-5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="row">
                    <td class="row-cell0">ITEM3</td>
                    <td class="row-cell1">DATA-COL-1</td>
                    <td class="row-cell2">DATA-COL-2</td>
                    <td class="row-cell3">DATA-COL-3</td>
                    <td class="row-cell4">DATA-COL-4</td>
                    <td class="row-cell5">DATA-COL-5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="row">
                    <td class="row-cell0">ITEM4</td>
                    <td class="row-cell1">DATA-COL-1</td>
                    <td class="row-cell2">DATA-COL-2</td>
                    <td class="row-cell3">DATA-COL-3</td>
                    <td class="row-cell4">DATA-COL-4</td>
                    <td class="row-cell5">DATA-COL-5</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="row">
                    <td class="row-cell0">ITEM5</td>
                    <td class="row-cell1">DATA-COL-1</td>
                    <td class="row-cell2">DATA-COL-2</td>
                    <td class="row-cell3">DATA-COL-3</td>
                    <td class="row-cell4">DATA-COL-4</td>
                    <td class="row-cell5">DATA-COL-5</td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
  </table>
```

Only one class="row" applied to all rows, and one class for each column, also applied to all rows.

Peace! :)

Comment: That's good, i also suggest you to use the latest version by changing the script src (URL) to `https://unpkg.com/xlsx/dist/xlsx.full.min.js` (remove the `@0.15.1`). Today the last version is `0.17.4`